# Highlight an Edge in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz

How might one highlight an edge in graphviz? I'd like to highlight the edge between D and E. One thing I've tried is to put a transparent edge between them on top of the existing edge, but Graphviz does not want to let them overlap the way I would like, instead placing the edges side by side.

I would like a yellow highlight around the edge from D to E.

[image: extra edge side by side instead]

```
 graph K5 {
    graph [splines = false, layout=circo];
    edge [penwidth=3];
    node [shape=circle];
    A;
    B;
    C;
    D;
    E;
    {
        edge [color="red"];
        A -- B;
        A -- C;
        C -- D;
        B -- D;
        C -- E;
    }

    {
        edge [color="blue"];
        node [comment="Wildcard node added automatic in EG."];
        D -- E;
        A -- E;
        B -- C;
        B -- E;
        A -- D;
    }

    {
        edge [color="#95a616aa" penwidth=5];
        node [comment="Wildcard node added automatic in EG."];
        E -- D;
    }

}
```

Comment: For some reason, setting splines=true (as the question asker does in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65642349/how-can-i-prevent-edges-from-being-drawn-over-each-other-in-graphviz?rq=1 )allows the edges to overlap. If anybody could explain this phenomenon or provide a more robust way to highlight edges, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but look at colorlist example here (http://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/color/)

```
graph K5 {
    graph [splines = false, layout=circo];
    edge [penwidth=3];
    node [shape=circle];
    A;
    B;
    C;
    D;
    E;
    {
        edge [color="red"];
        A -- B;
        A -- C;
        C -- D;
        B -- D;
        C -- E;
    }

    {
        edge [color="blue"];
        node [comment="Wildcard node added automatic in EG."];
        D -- E;
        A -- E;
        B -- C;
        B -- E;
        A -- D;
    }

    {
        // see color/colorlist http://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/color/
        edge [color="lightpink:red:orange:orange:red:lightpink" penwidth=1];
        node [comment="Wildcard node added automatic in EG."];
        E -- D;
    }

}
```

Giving:
[image]